# How can you setText of a TextView in another TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I want the text I have in `TextView1` to be displayed in `TextView2`, for example:

```
TextView1.setText("hello");

TextView2.setText(ContentOf.TextView1)
```

What do I have to type instead of

```
 "ContentOf.TextView1"
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the text of `TextView1` with `getText()` and set it to the `TextView2` as follows...

```
TextView1.setText("hello");

TextView2.setText(TextView1.getText())
```

Answer (score 1):

`TextView1.getText()` returns a CharacterSequence which is the text set in the corresponding TextView.

So,

```
TextView2.setText(TextView1.getText().toString());
```

Or even just,

```
TextView2.setText(TextView1.getText());
```